# When the Horn of Blasting explodes, do I still get the normal attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

There is a 20% chance that the Horn of Blasting explodes on use. But it's not clear if this happens instead of the normal effect, or in addition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common reading states the effect takes place first, *then* the horn is destroyed.

---

However, when in doubt, use what Xanathar's Guide to Everything tells us:

> If two or more things happen at the same time on a character or monster's turn, the person at the game table-whether player or DM-who controls that creature decides the order in which those things happen.

The blower decides whether the horn is destroyed before the effect happens, or after.